# How to do nested schema extraction using Marshmallow?

Tags: python, marshmallow

I am trying to extract values from api and pass on to marshmallow to extract the nested schema and simplify it to flat schema.Below is what I tried but its not working

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class ArtistSchema(Schema):
    ids = fields.Int()
    name = fields.Str()
    

class AlbumSchema(Schema):
    artist = fields.Pluck(ArtistSchema, field_name=('ids','name',)) # concept


in_data = {'artist': [{'id': 42, 'name': 'Douglas Adams'}]}
dumped = AlbumSchema().dump(in_data, many=True)
```

Expected output is :

```
    {
       'id': 42,
       'name': 'Douglas Adams'
    }
```